# URL modified from each click after change in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

i am modifying my php script to SEO friendly

when i click first time on link in test.php page it is displaying in url as  *htp://example/test/first*
working fine. 
when click on second time url as become      *htp://example/test/test/first*.test folder is keep on adding into URL

how to reslove this issue.

```
##test.php
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a  href='test/first'>testing</a> <br>
<body> 
</html>

##.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)  /test.php?$1 [L]
DirectoryIndex test.php
```

Comment: how the link that you clicked look like?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities to solve this.

1) Slash in front of the URL

```
 <a  href='/test/first'>testing</a>
```

which will only work if your website isn't contained in a sub directory of your web space

2) Absolute URL

```
 <a  href='http://www.example.com/test/first'>testing</a>
```

You can save this in a config file or something (baseUrl anyone?) and append it to links dynamically like this

```
 <a  href='<?=$cfg->baseUrl?>/test/first'>testing</a>
```

3) HTML

Set a base in your head-Tag like this

```
 <base href="http://example.com/">
```

which might break other paths on your site like image-paths and CSS paths